How can I specify for 1 record 1 table?
I am using the docx-templates to generate Word files by filling data to a template.
My template is a table, I expect 1 data row to be filled into a table on a single page.
However, I don't know how to accomplish it.
Here is my code:
import { createReport } from 'docx-templates';
let content = fs.readFileSync("./Check List Template.docx");
let rosterA=[
  { a: 'Operator4', count: 1, b: 'Operator6', c: 'Operator8' },
  { a: 'Operator5', count: 2, b: 'Operator6', c: 'Operator8' },
  { a: 'Operator5', count: 3, b: 'Operator1', c: 'Operator4' },
  { a: 'Operator6', count: 4, b: 'Operator8', c: 'Operator1' },
  { a: 'Operator6', count: 5, b: 'Operator4', c: 'Operator8' },
  { a: 'Operator4', count: 6, b: 'Operator6', c: 'Operator1' },
  { a: 'Operator8', count: 7, b: 'Operator6', c: 'Operator5' },
  { a: 'Operator8', count: 8, b: 'Operator6', c: 'Operator4' },
  { a: 'Operator', b: 'Operator8', count: 9, c: 'Operator5' },
  { a: 'Operator1', count: 10, b: 'Operator4', c: 'Operator6' },
  { a: 'Operator1', count: 11, b: 'Operator5', c: 'Operator6' }
]
const buffer = await createReport({
    template: content,
    data: {        
        rosterA        
    }
});
fs.writeFileSync("output.docx",buffer);

It is because SO do not accept a word as an attachment. I have uploaded my template Word file in jpg format only.


In word template Check List Template.docx, insert manual page break right before for loop end syntax, and next table/item will start on next page:
position cursor here, then go to: Insert > Page Break +++END-FOR item+++
Insert a page break in Word
